# Global function in lua

Tags: function, lua, global

Is there a way to have a function in Lua that can be accessed from any module in a project without having to first require it?

something like:

```
module(..., package.seeall);
function globFoo()
       print('global foo called');
end
```

and have it called from somwhere else, like main

```
--main

globFoo();
```

without requiring it?

Comment: Why the heck would you want that?

Comment: So that I could have certain functionality accessible everywhere in my project without having to go through the (all be it mild) inconvenience of requiring it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A module is just a Lua script. You can do whatever you want there; you don't even have to call `module` in your module script. Indeed, `module` is [generally considered harmful these days](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued), which is why it was deprecated in Lua 5.2.

Really, it's a matter of simply moving your code around:

```
function globFoo()
       print('global foo called');
end
module(..., package.seeall); --Module created after global function
```

So yes, you can have a module modify the global table. I would very much suggest that you don't (because it creates implicit ordering between Lua scripts, which makes it hard to know which script uses which stuff). But you can do it.

Answer (score 4):

A sample of how this is done :

in global.lua (where the global function is located) :

```
globalFunction1 = function(params)
    print("I am globalFunction1")
end
```

In the calling file, caller.lua :

```
globalFunction1(params)    -- This will call the global function above
```